# Explanation for issues of type "ResourceCycle": when generate signed Apk

Tags: android

I am getting error  after update to appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1 on generating the signed apk.

```
Error:Error: Style Resource definition cycle: TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title => TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title => TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title [ResourceCycle]
```

Comment: Faced same issue, I added a solution.

Answer (score 15):

**Temporary but Working Solution**: 
I was searching for the solution for about two days but I was unable to create signed apk, finally I found the answer on this thread: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203407

Just put these 3 lines in your 'app' **build.gradle** file under **android()**

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
```

finally your build.gradle file will be like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
//Here the magic Begins
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
//Here the magic Ends
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('src/main/libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
}
```

I hope this answer will help you. This will create your build, later when proper 24 support libraries release available, you have to change it properly.

Comment: @Pankaj, if this answer solved your issue, then kindly mark this as answer, so others find it useful.

Answer (score 9):

Faced same issue, here's right fix for it.

Start your SDK Manager, goto Extras section, here you can see update for Support Library. Install it.

Then open build.gradle/app.gradle 
change

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
```

Problem solved! cheers.

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203407
check it for more details...

paste it in your **Gradle** of your project

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: Faced same issue, I added a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade local maven repository for support libraries.

Reverting back to 26 solves my problems.

See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203546#c10