# why my dependences version changes from 23.0.0 to 24.0.0-alpha1?

Tags: android

I want to move to previous version how I can move please suggest me.

[image]

Comment: Just change your build.gradle. Post it.

Comment: is it possible to back previous version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36571575/2678584 this work for me